# Is There a Placeholder Variable in Octave?

Tags: octave

I'm trying to get the max indexes by row from a matrix. To do this, I'm doing:

```
[throwaway, indexes] = max(blah, [], 2);
```

The variable "throwaway," would store values I don't want anymore and would never use, and I don't want to waste memory on it. Is there some way to indicate I don't want anything put into that throwaway variable? Something like undef in Perl, perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can throw away return arguments with `~` for examples if func returns two arguments only v will be available after the following `[~, v] = func()`